# How can I improve my pdf quality? I am using Jspdf and html2canvs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to generate pdf file from my app. The thing is that I can generate pdf but it's not to the standard.

I can see there are some difference in the text quality when i download the pdf. By no means these are bad quality but it is not a good quality also.

I am trying all the possible solutions i found online but it really doesn't improve the quality.

Since there are not many code i won't describe the code here but here is the code pen link for my problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-drake-lbfsuh?file=/src/App.js

You can click on the download button to see the quality.

For comparison sake here is another online tool that can generate full quality pdf. You can
try to compare these 2
https://www.zoho.com/invoice/free-invoice-generator.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the loss in quality comes from the use of html2canvas which is not necessary here. You can convert your html element to pdf directly like this :

```
const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.html(document.getElementById('testing'), {
  callback: function () {
      pdf.save('print.pdf');
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work at all, It giving me weird pdf when i try to download it in codesandbox, you can modify and try it yourself

Comment: works for me : https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-night-3d5sjj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi, yep your solution works but not in a way i wanted. 
Reason being I wanted a pdf with single page with potrait ratio. So I change to `new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4")`  when i change to this. The pdf downloaded is giving me 2 page rather than 1 page and you may see in the example the font size become too big for an a4 paper, My default font size is `14px`